# SwiftUI's Text foreground in dark mode

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a text that renders an AttributedString from some String. The problem I'm having is that in dark mode, the text is shown in black colour with blue as hyperlink colours and thus the text can't be seen.
I have tried to do the following, but it has no effect at all:

```
ScrollView {
                if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                    if let data = job.description.data(using: .unicode),
                       let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                                                                      documentAttributes: nil) {
                        if colorScheme == .dark {
                            Text(AttributedString(attributedString))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        } else {
                            Text(AttributedString(attributedString))
                        }
                    }
...
```

Is there any way I can change the font colour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably your document has defined text color inside HTML, so you should to replace attributed string corresponding attributes.

Comment: What do you exactly mean?